# Is it possible to create iOS application with windows cordova?

Tags: cordova

I see many good examples with starting app creating with cordova, but I have only windows PC, Can I create iOS app without mac with cordova? I can't find the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Cordova app on a Windows machine (design your HTML, model your javascript logic, add plugins etc) and debug it in your browser, but the actual building of the iOS app can only be done on a Mac or using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) (cloud service for building).

Comment: Thanks for answer, But Can I compile cordova project by PhoneGap Build?

Comment: If you're in the startup process of your app, you could choose to start a Phonegap app instead of a Cordova application, they're quite similar. If you already started a Cordova app, there are some small changes to make in configuration before being able to build with Phonegap Build. Have a look at this [article](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/convert_cordova_phonegap/).

Answer (score 0):

See [iOS Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/)

> Apple® tools required to build iOS applications only run on the OS X
>   operating system on Intel-based Macs.